# How to prevent component focusability java swing

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextarea, propertychangelistener

in my java swing application, i want to display an information text (JTextArea in the top of the screen) whenever i click on a field of the form. To do this i implemented the interface PropertyChangeListener 
as follow :

```
private final class FocusChangeHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        final String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
        if (!"permanentFocusOwner".equals(propertyName)) {
            return;
        }

        final Component focusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();

        final String focusHint = (focusOwner instanceof JComponent) ? ((String) ValidationComponentUtils.getInputHint((JComponent) focusOwner))
                : null;

        infoArea.setText(focusHint);
        infoAreaPane.setVisible(focusHint != null);
    }
}
```

my problem is that whenever the value of the infoArea changes it gains focus and the scrollbar return to the top.

I want to prevent this behavior, i want to update the value of the infoArea without putting focus on it.

I tried the method .setFocusable(false) but the scrollbar keep on returning to the top of the screen.

Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you try to use `requestFocus()` on the component that originated the event? See if it helps.

Comment: I just wrote a test program, and I am not seeing the behavior you describe.  Calling setText on a JTextArea does not give it focus.  It causes the JTextArea to scroll to the bottom, not to the top.  Is your JTextArea in a JScrollPane by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack for this problem.

```
private final class FocusChangeHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        final String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
        if (!"permanentFocusOwner".equals(propertyName)) {
            return;
        }

        final Component focusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();

        final String focusHint = (focusOwner instanceof JComponent) ? ((String) ValidationComponentUtils.getInputHint((JComponent) focusOwner))
                : null;
        final int scrollBarPosition = panelScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
        infoAreaPane.setVisible(focusHint != null);
        infoArea.setText(infoHint);
        if(focusHint != null) {
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() { 
                       panelScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollBarPosition);
                   }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
infoAreaPane.setVisible(focusHint != null);
```

Comment: i tried this solution but the infoArea still gain focus :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a component to gain focus you can use:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(...);
textArea.setFocusable( false );
```

> but the scrollbar keep on returning to the top of the screen

Don't use `setText()`.

Instead you can try to update the `Document` directly. Maybe something like:

```
Document doc = textArea.getDocument()
doc.remove(...);
doc.insertString(...);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @camickr but it doesn't work. I tried also to save the scroll position, set the text and then put back the position and it doesn't work